# How can I convert a column that contains an array represented as a string into two columns in AWS Glue?

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, parquet

I have an AWS Glue Dynamic DataFrame with a column named **array** containing the following data:

```
[123.123, 456.456]
```

When doing a printSchema() I get that the column is of type String.

Is there any way to split this column into two other columns without converting it to a Spark DF using `toDF()`?

Comment: Can't think of direct conversion with DynamicFrame. Any reason, you don't want to do it with PySpark or Pandas transformation?